# Sharepoint REST - Can we update file metadata while uploading file itself?

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, office365, sharepoint-api

1. Using below Endpoint we can upload file to sharepoint:
   https://domain.example.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("FolderRelativeUrl")/Files/add(url="File",overwrite=true)
2. Using below endpoint we can update the metadata for specific file:
   https://domain.example.com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(URL)/ListItemAllFields

Is it possible to update metadata when we are uploading file itself?
And same while retrieve, we need to fetch metadata along with file.

Basically I am trying to avoid 2 separate calls? Does SharePoint API support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint can't provide a REST API to achieve it.

As a workaround, we can use CSOM(C#) to achieve it.

```
public Boolean UploadDocument(String fileName, String filePath, List metaDataList)   
{  
    SP.ClientContext ctx = new SP.ClientContext("http://yoursharepointURL");  
    Web web = ctx.Web;  
    FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();  
    newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C: \TestFile.doc");  
    newFile.Url = "/" + fileName;  
    List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle(“Shared Documents”);  
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);  
    context.Load(uploadFile);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    SPClient.ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;  
    //Set the metadata  
    string docTitle = string.Empty;  
    item["Title"] = docTitle;
    item.Update();  
    context.ExecuteQuery();  
}
```

If you want to call web service using Ajax from UI, we can create a custom web service with CSOM(C#), then consume the web service using Ajax.

Comment: Still 2 separate calls? OP question is can he set metadata while uploading itself..?

Comment: The OOTB REST API can't provide one call to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for answering question.  I wanted to know if there is any ways where using sharepoint API we can update metadata at the time of uploading file itself. I guess answer is NO.

Comment: Using SharePoint REST API, we have to call the request twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's frustrating, but you can upload the initial version and set metadata in a single call. But not upload new version and set metadata, only as separate calls. I am transfering files from a DMS which can have multiple versions, and the version history in Sharepoint will not match. To make it consistent, I also transfer the initial version and metadata as two calls. The customer is informed, and the version history is ok. The file import shows as an empty version.